# List of English Nouns and their Plural Form

Tags: english

Is there a list of nouns and their plurals?

E.g. apple apples, genius geni, roof rooves, etc.

I have the GCIDE dictionary but that only contains singular nouns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This python package can pluralize words for you, you can just run your entire dictionary through it to get the plural forms: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#pluralization

For this you first need Python, I myself use [winpython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/), but any python installation would do. You can then download the pattern package here: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the English nouns with their plural forms from the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page).